# Ubuntu Server issues with LVM

Tags: mount, lvm

I need help with my Ubuntu Server 16.04.
After reinstalling, I've noticed that some LVM2 units were not mounted, unlike the others that was in EXT4.

I've followed the instructions in [this link](https://quonn.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/how-to-mount-lvm-partition-on-ubuntu/)

Everything was ok until the cmd `vgchange -a y`, when I've noticed that all the examples had shown "logical volume" with 1 or 2. But in my case, it has shown "0 logical volume(s) in volume group 'BackUp' now active".

After that, when I try to follow it by executing `lvscan`, nothing else shows up, not allowing the cursor for new commands.

I cannot complete the instructions to mount my units.

There is someway I can access those files?

A software, some other way to mount or anything else?